# How to program my own occurs check?

Tags: prolog

I want to program my own occurs check in Prolog. Later I wanna use this check for my own mgu.

I got:

`occurs_check(A,B) :- var(B), A \== B, !, true.`
`occurs_check(A,B) :- var(B), A == B, !, fail.`

But I dont know how to write the recursion for terms. Maybe someone can help me?
Thanks!

Comment: I don't know how to write the occurs check but I think you may find either [`=../2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=%3D../2) or [`term_variables/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=term_variables/2) interesting and possibly useful.

Comment: So you really want `occurs_check/2` to succeed if the variable is *not* in the term, and fail when it is in the term? That seems opposite of what one would expect.

Comment: @lurker I think that's necessary (but not sufficient) because the point of the occurs check is to prevent recursive terms from being generated (think `X = foo(X)`).

Comment: @DanielLyons ok. I reckon in that case, I'd call it a `does_not_occur_check/2`. :)